# How to cast only eligible columns

Tags: r, dataframe, class, casting

If I have hundreds of `character` columns in a dataframe, but some of them have values who can be converted in `numeric`, since they are all `integer` or `float`, and other can't, since some of them are actually `character`. How can I cast only the eligible columns into numeric?

Comment: could you please provide a reprex?

Comment: Without a sample data, it is not clear what you would like to achieve, you could pick the known columns (e.g. `cols <- colnames(df)[grepl('columnname', colnames(df))]` and then `df %>% mutate_at(vars(cols), ~as.numeric)`.

Comment: You can get your numeric columns in the dataframe with `dplyr ::select_if(data, is.numeric)` from dplyr package.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to first define a function to cast a single vector into numbers if it can be turned to numeric without generating `NA`s, then `lapply` this to the dataframe.

```
x = c("a", "3", "")
y = c("3", "3", "3")
z = c("2", NA, "3")
df = data.frame(x,y,z)

castIfNumeric <- function(x) if( all(!is.na(as.numeric(na.omit(x)))) ) as.numeric(x) else x
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, castIfNumeric))
str(df)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: chr  "a" "3" ""
 $ y: num  3 3 3
 $ z: num  2 NA 3
```